# PHP: Why is date made into an array?

Tags: php

Why is this string being made into an array and how do I stop it please?

**Snippet: (to get date)**

```
public function setDate(){
        $this->date = date("Y-m-d");
        return $date;
    }


public function getDate(){
    return $this->date;
}


$date = getDate();
```

**Snippet: (part of query)**

```
        ->where_equal_to(
            array(
                'sales_date' => $date
            )
        )
```

When you dump the query its doing this...

**Output:**

---

```
array(1) { ["sales_date"]=> array(11) { ["seconds"]=> int(42) ["minutes"]=> int(10) ["hours"]=> int(14) ["mday"]=> int(3) ["wday"]=> int(1) ["mon"]=> int(10) ["year"]=> int(2011) ["yday"]=> int(275) ["weekday"]=> string(6) "Monday" ["month"]=> string(7) "October" [0]=> int(1317647442) } }
```

---

instead of something like this...

---

**Output:**

```
array(1) { ["sales_date"]=> "2011-10-03 00:00:00" }
```

---

Comment: This is certainly missing something. For one, `'sales_date' => '$date'
` won't work the way you think it will because variable substitutions don't happen in single quotes....

Comment: It looks like you're using some kind of DB library or ORM. You probably should mention that, since it's probably what is doing this (PHP doesn't tend to take strings and randomly make them into arrays).

Comment: Its a very basic custom query class thats all...

Comment: Please post the code of that "basic custom query class" then. The snippets you've posted are not sufficient to diagnose the problem. (See also - http://pscode.org/sscce.html)

Comment: Pointless, your looking way to into this. When you dump $date before doing anything with it you get an array like the one output above. Only want a string. Was just hoping someone clued up could explain why?

Comment: I think it is because of the function `where_equal_to`. Try exploring the definition of this function.

Comment: @Alex Don't turn on people for asking for more information. They are trying to help.

Comment: @Alex - it most certainly isn't pointless to ask for that; there is in fact a very glaring error in your code. Myself and others have pointed out the problem, but we can't show you where in your code it is happening because you're refusing to post the relevant code. The bug will be in your "very simple class".

Comment: No one is doing anything of the sort Brendan. Too many people here tend to look way to into it that's all and make many assumptions. The query has absolutely nothing to do with it so it would be pointless. See the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling the PHP function `getdate()` rather than $obj->getDate(), so it's returning an array based off of the return value from the built-in function.

https://www.php.net/getdate

Comment: Thank you very much, explains everything.

Answer (score 2):

The array you're seeeing is the output of PHP's [`getdate()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php).

Somewhere in your code, you're calling `getdate()` instead of your custom `getDate()` function (I presume the latter is in a class, otherwise it would throw a compiler error trying to redeclare an existing function). That's where your problem lies. You haven't shown the relevant bit of code, but it's probably inside your class. You may need to call it as `$myvar = $this->getDate();` or `$myvar = $someobject->getDate();` instead of just `$myvar = getDate();`.

For what it's worth, in case you can't change the class itself, the `[0]` element of the returned array is a timestamp, which is easy enough to convert back into a date of any format using the `date()` function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, jprofitt got there before you thats all.

Answer (score 0):

You can't redeclare [`getDate()`<sup>[docs]</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php) because it already exists. Also, you forgot to

- declare instance for your class
- you're calling getDate (function) instead of getDate (method)

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/9fb88/3